# Can't get methods in a Class to work

Tags: php, char, switch-statement

```
static private  function removeAccentedLetters($input){
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        $input[$i]=self::simplify($input[$i]);
    }
    return $input;
}

static private function simplify($in){

   switch ($in) {
   case 'Á':
          return 'A';
   case 'á':
          return 'a';
   default:
         return $in;     
   }
}
```

This is the code. Doesn't work. Any thoughts?
Oh yeah. It always enters the dafault exit for any input. perhaps it is somethig to do with how php handles chars X strings? I don't know.

Comment: Please be more descriptive of the surrounding context.

Comment: hmm. The switch statement always return the default: . Even when the other cases are input

Comment: Is the character set of the file the same as the string?

Comment: Oh, and I usually use `iconv($charset_in,'ASCII//TRANSLIT',$string);`, and presto, gone are your diacritics (and the euro sign even becomes EUR for instance).

Comment: Don't you require `break;` between cases to ensure they don't execute on top of one another? Or does having a return preclude the requirement of a `break`?

Comment: The problem was due to using latin stuff inside the code. On another issue, I think the return statement overrides everything, doesn't it? I don't know either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of switching the character itself, switch the character code. It's dangerous to embed ASCII Extended characters directly in a string, raw. Sometimes even the editor you are using to write the code may save the characters incorrectly, if you have the wrong encoding specified.

Comment: Hm... Yeah perhaps, but it should work as it is, shouldn´t it?

Comment: It's always a little dangerous to embed ASCII Extended characters raw in code like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) instead:

```
$input = str_replace(array('Á', 'á'), array('A', 'a'), $input);
```

That does the exact same work as your switch statement.

Comment: Not really - you meant: `$input = str_replace(array('Á', 'A'), array('á', 'a'), $input);` - and see dangers of embedding ASCII

Comment: I agree with Peter; It doesn't really matter how you do the actual replacing. As long as you are embedding extended ASCII characters directly, there is the possibility for the code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I changed the code slightly to this

```
        switch ($in) {
        case 'B':
            return 'A';
        case 'b':
            return 'a';
        default:
            return $in;     
    }
```

for testing purposes and it worked. Thanks to all.